# How to remove specific part of a string in R

Tags: r, string

I am new to R, need help...
I have a .txt file with a line:

```
"[Thurs May 29 24:12:57 2001] 77\tExpFcn-2\tlane\tLibrary/Royalbikers/Presoms/Sec32/Initially3-3-2-08-Alpha-vs-Beta.yg\t1\t-1\t3084\t0\t1\t\005\b\002"
```

I want to edit the txt file so that in the output I can remove everything except the date/time info in `"[...]"` and the file path `"Library...."`

I have used str_extract function but cannot get the pattern right.

```
string <- readLines("string.txt")
library(stringr)

str_extract(string, " some pattern")
```

is split.string also a option?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  You can get the first pattern with `str_extract_all(str1, '(?<=\\[)[^]]+')[[1]]`  Regarding the second pattern, I am not sure where it start/end.

Comment: How about `str_extract(xx, "\\[.*\\]")` and `str_extract(xx, "\tLibrary[^\t]*\t")`?

Comment: the expected output is: "[Thurs May 29 24:12:57 2001] Library/Royalbikers/Presoms/Sec32/Initially3-3-2-08-Alpha-vs-Beta.yg"

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
x <- "[Thurs May 29 24:12:57 2001]77\tExpFcn-2\tlane\tLibrary/Royalbikers/Presoms/Sec32/Initially3-3-2-08-Alpha-vs-Beta.yg\t1\t-1\t3084\t0\t1\t\005\b\002"
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])")
```

By way of explanation

`(?<=START)` paired with `(?=END)` forms a block where you find any pattern matches between `START` and `END`.

Between those two, you put the pattern you want to find.  If you wanted to find `car` between `[` and `]`, you'd use `(?<=\\[)car(?=\\])`.

the pattern `.+?` is a way of saying any characters.

Answer (score 1):

You just need base R, no additional library required.

```
> string
[1] "[Thurs May 29 24:12:57 2001] 77\tExpFcn-2\tlane\tLibrary/Royalbikers/Presoms/Sec32/Initially3-3-2-08-Alpha-vs-Beta.yg\t1\t-1\t3084\t0\t1\t\005\b\002"

> part1 <- substring(string, (regexpr("[", string, fixed = T)[1]) + 1, (regexpr("]", string, fixed = T)[1]) - 1)
> part1
[1] "Thurs May 29 24:12:57 2001"

> part2 <- substring(string, regexpr("Library", string, fixed = T)[1], nchar(string ))
> part2
[1] "Library/Royalbikers/Presoms/Sec32/Initially3-3-2-08-Alpha-vs-Beta.yg\t1\t-1\t3084\t0\t1\t\005\b\002"

> result <- paste(part1,", ",part2)
> result
[1] "Thurs May 29 24:12:57 2001 ,  Library/Royalbikers/Presoms/Sec32/Initially3-3-2-08-Alpha-vs-Beta.yg\t1\t-1\t3084\t0\t1\t\005\b\002"
```

Comment: hey.. thanks for the reply.. but in the part2 substring I want it from "Library" to "Beta.yg"  not uptill "b\002"

Comment: the expected output is:  "[Thurs May 29 24:12:57 2001] Library/Royalbikers/Presoms/Sec32/Initially3-3-2-08-Alpha-vs-Beta.yg"

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping.. I used your code as well as I found an expression that suits my question...

x<- str_split( string, "\t")
- this will create a list of all the characters that are separated by a "\t"

part1 <- sapply(part2, function(x){x[1]})
part2 <- sapply(part2, function(x){x[2]})

ans <- paste(part1,part2,sep = " ")
ans